# Extraction of rows with condition using R

Tags: r

I have a table as below. I want to extract the rows having all `value >= 0.1`.
How can I do that?

Matrix:

```
gene    Sample A        Sample B          Sample C  
gene1   28.76975267    18.47245374      24.14395137 
gene2   0               0               0.13841512  
gene3   31.06797745    36.00742451      61.29714172
```

The matrix I need:

```
gene    Sample A      Sample B      Sample C    
gene1   28.76975267  18.47245374    24.14395137 
gene3   31.06797745  36.00742451    61.29714172
```

Comment: Do you mean having *all* values >=0.1?

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rowSums` to create a logical index and subset the rows based on that

```
df1[rowSums(df1[-1] >= 0.01)==3,]
#   gene  SampleA  SampleB  SampleC
#1 gene1 28.76975 18.47245 24.14395
#3 gene3 31.06798 36.00742 61.29714
```

Or another option is `Reduce` with `&`

```
df1[Reduce(`&`, lapply(df1[-1], `>=`, 0.01)),]
```

NOTE: Both the solutions are vectorized solutions

Answer (score 2):

We can use `apply` with index 1 and check if all the values in the row are >= 0.1

```
df[apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) all(x >= 0.01)), ]

#   gene  SampleA  SampleB  SampleC
#1 gene1 28.76975 18.47245 24.14395   
#3 gene3 31.06798 36.00742 61.29714
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to use the following code:

```
data <- data[which(data$sampleA >= 0.01 & data$sampleB >= 0.01 & data$sampleC >= 0.01), ]
```

This is assuming you mean you want to get rid of all rows that contain at least one value that is < 0.01?

MWE:

```
data <- data.frame(sampleA = c(28.76, 0, 31.06),
                   sampleB = c(18.42, 0, 36.01),
                   sampleC = c(24.14, 0, 36.01))

data <- data[which(data$sampleA >= 0.01 &
                   data$sampleB >= 0.01 &
                   data$sampleC >= 0.01), ]
print(data)

#   sampleA sampleB sampleC
# 1   28.76   18.42   24.14
# 3   31.06   36.01   36.01
```

Comment: Hi, I did this, but got the result as : data
[1] gene    SampleA SampleB SampleC
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Comment: Hello this is most likely because either your columns are not in numeric format or you are using the wrong column names after the $ extension.

Comment: I will provide a MWE in my answer.